# "GNU Make not found. Try setting the environment variable GNUMAKE."

Tags: macos, installation, gnu-make, sbcl

I am trying to install Steel Bank Common Lisp as described in [this article](http://www.lothlorien.com/kf6gpe/?p=24).

However, when I do this step:

```
sh-3.2# INSTALL_ROOT=/usr/local sh install.sh
```

I get this error:

```
GNU Make not found. Try setting the environment variable GNUMAKE.
```

How, exactly, do I install GNU Make and set the environment variable GNUMAKE on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the Developer Tools that came on a DVD ROM with the machine. GNU make is included in XCode (version 3.81 on my Leopard box).

If you don't have the ROM, you can sign up as a developer (for free) and [download a disk image](http://developer.apple.com/).

Answer (score 0):

To install GNUMAKE:

`# pkgin install gmake`